# Remove columns from table view javafx

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I have a table view in javafx and I add dynamically the columns because I don't know the number of the columns. I want when I click in a button all the rows and columns of the tableView to be removed. I have the code below. I want before I add new data in the table to remove all the columns from it. I tried a lot of things that I found online but nothing worked. Thanks.

```
public void handleEventsClick(){
    String tableName = (String) events.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();

    ObservableList<ObservableList> transitionEvents = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    tableColumns = new TableColumn[traEv.size()];

    int trEvSize = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < traEv.size();i++){
        ArrayList<TransitionSubsequencePair> tep = traEv.get(i); 

        TableColumn tc = new TableColumn("TrEv:" + i);
        tableColumns[i] = tc;
            final int j = i;
            tc.setCellValueFactory(new Callback<CellDataFeatures<ObservableList,String>,ObservableValue<String>>(){                    
                public ObservableValue<String> call(CellDataFeatures<ObservableList, String> param) {                                                                                              
                    return new SimpleStringProperty(param.getValue().get(j).toString());                        
                }                    
            });
            eventsTableView.getColumns().addAll(tc);
    }

    ObservableList<String> row = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    row.clear();
    for(int i = 0; i < traEv.size();i++){
        ArrayList<TransitionSubsequencePair> tep = traEv.get(i); 

        ArrayList<String> seenTables = new ArrayList<String>();
        for(TransitionSubsequencePair tre: tep){
            System.out.println(tre.getTable());
            String lala = "";
            if(tre.getTable().equals(tableName) && (!seenTables.contains(tre.getTable()) || seenTables.isEmpty())){
                System.out.println(i);
                lala += tre.getTransition() + ":" + tre.getSubsequence() + ",";
                row.add(lala);
                seenTables.add(tre.getTable());
            }
            System.out.println("--"+lala);
        }


    }
    transitionEvents.add(row);


    eventsTableView.setItems(transitionEvents); // finally add data to tableview


}
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

To remove all data:

```
eventsTableView.getItems().clear();
```

To remove all columns:

```
eventsTableView.getColumns().clear();
```

Comment: Again.. you were 10 secs faster than me ;-)

Comment: thanks it really helped me (I had to change something more to work but your answer helped me a lot).